# Accelerate table adjustment

Tags: performance, powershell, foreach, import-from-csv

I need to combine three text files in CSV Format to one under following conditions:

In *pricelist-1.txt* there is a `ProductID`, which points to the table *cnet-product-de.txt* - also to `ProductID`.
On the *cnet-product-de.txt* the `MarketingTextID` points to the table *cnet-text-de.txt* - to `ID`.

Now I want to combine the three files with a script to a CSV-file.
Finally, ProductID; Description; ManufacturerPartNumber; NetPrice; NetRetailPrice + Text should be uploaded from cnet-text-en.txt.

The script works, but it needs forever (more than 8 hours) cause of the double Loop and the huge txt files (up to 300'000 rows).
Has anyone an idea how to speed up my script? If you did not understand the conditions don't hesitate to ask, because I'm not a native speaker.

```
#start timer
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

#Declaration
$temp = @()
$merged = @()

#clear existent txt
Clear-Content -Path "C:\temp\ALSO\merged.txt"

#read CSVs
$csvprice = Import-csv -path "C:\temp\ALSO\pricelist-1.txt" -Delimiter ';'
$csvtext = Import-Csv -path "C:\temp\ALSO\cnet-text-de.txt" -Delimiter "`t"  

#Read CSV / Group by MarketingTextID / delete multiple ProductID entries
$PAMID = Import-Csv -path "C:\temp\ALSO\cnet-product-de\cnet-product-de.txt" -Delimiter "`t" |
    Select-Object ProductID, MarketingTextID | 
    Group-Object ProductID | 
    ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ProductID       = $_.group.ProductID | Get-Unique
        MarketingTextID = $_.Group.MarketingTextID -join ','
    }
}

#get a single row from $PAMID
ForEach ($ID1 in $PAMID) {

    #Split the MarketingTextIDs
    $1 = $ID1.MarketingTextID.Split(",")[0]
    $2 = $ID1.MarketingTextID.Split(",")[1]
    $3 = $ID1.MarketingTextID.Split(",")[2]
    $4 = $ID1.MarketingTextID.Split(",")[3]

    #get a single row from $csvtext
    foreach ($ID in $csvtext) {

        #Comparison with the individual MarketingTextIDs and add to $temp variable
        if (($ID.ID -eq $1) -Or ($ID.ID -eq $2) -Or ($ID.ID -eq $3) -Or ($ID.ID -eq $3)) {
            $temp += $ID1 | Select-Object *, @{name = "Text"; expression = {$ID.Text}}
            break
        }
        else {
            continue
        }

    }
}

#Get a single row from $temp
foreach ($tempid in $temp) {

    #Declaration
    $tid = $tempid.ProductID
    $tmid = $tempid.MarketingTextID
    $ttext = $tempid.Text

    #Get a single row from $csvprice
    foreach ($Price in $csvprice) {

        #Comparison ProductIDs and add to $merged Variable
        if ($Price.ProductID -eq $tid) {
            $Price = $Price | select *, @{name = "MarketingTextID"; expression = {$tmid}}
            $Price = $Price | select *, @{name = "Text"; expression = {$ttext}}
            $merged += $Price
            break
        }
        else {
            continue
        }
    }

}
#Export to txt in UTF8 format
$merged | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Also\merged.txt" -Encoding UTF8

#Exit and output timer
$stopwatch.stop()
Write-Host "The script took $($stopwatch.elapsed.totalminutes) minutes"
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `Join-Object` cmdlet and the `-contains` operator, I think...

Comment: I agree that Join-Object is probably the way to go.  What you are trying to do resembles a relational join,  the sort of thing SQL is very good at.  Most database systems contain an optimizer that will figure out a fairly efficient strategy, one that may involve creating indexing info in main memory.  Your algorithm looks like it's brute force.  You just can't do things that way when you have this much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to cross join 300000 row CSVs then you're looking at *thirty billion* iterations of the inner loop. Even if each takes well under a millisecond you will be looking at hours: as you are.

You need to reduce the number of iterations. And currently you are doing a `continue` at the end of the loop... and you only look for the first result. So the inner loop is only getting a single value, thus:

> ```
> foreach ($ID in $csvtext){
>   if(($ID.ID -eq $1) -Or ($ID.ID -eq $2) -Or ($ID.ID -eq $3) -Or ($ID.ID -eq $3)) {
>     $temp += $ID1 | select *,@{name="Text";expression={$ID.Text}}
>     break
>   } else { 
>      continue
>   }
> }
> ```

Can become:

```
$opts = $1, $2, $3, $4;
$innerRes = $csvtext | Where-Object $_.ID -in $opts |
             select-object -first 1 |
             select-object *,@{name="Text";expression={$_.Text}}
```

A similar transform on the outer loop means you can assign the pipeline to a result rather than appending to an array (the former is quicker than the latter).

Generally: using the core paradigms of a platform (in PowerShell: pipelines) will generally work better than using those of other lines.

Finally: It may be this is a case where your tooling is wrong: upload each CSV to a database and use SQL (which is designed for this kind of operation) but you'll need to use set operations in SQL not imperative code.

Comment: _Generally[...]pipelines_ I really like this one. I think it could be supplemented to object oriented behavior, which would make the heavy usage of split operations obsolete.